# Nutch tips how to test it

Tags: testing, nutch

For my testing purpose I want to make small fetch-generate-parse-index cycle. Now I have about thousands records in my database and when I run index it starts indexing many many records which takes hours.
Do you have any tip how to test this use case? Is there any way to generate limited number of pages generated in one batch?

Well I generally appreciate for any advice on testing Nutch 2.2.1 with Hbase and Solr 4.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldnt take ages for a thousand records in the database, have you enabled multithreading?

Comment: Check this post, its more Nutch 1.4 but should be relatively similar for 2.2
http://amac4.blogspot.com/2013/07/nutch-crawling-slowly-multi-threaded.html